# What is the first notable use of the name Chaim (חיים)

Tags: history, names

What is the first notable use of the name Chaim (חיים) and what is its origin?

Comment: There's the tosafist R Chaim Kohein in the 12th century

Comment: צמח בן חיים גאון - ninth century

Comment: The idea of naming someone after life itself, dates back to the sixth day of creation